# Cannot connect to Sensebox: Unknown FQBN: missing platform release arduino:samd referenced by board sensebox:samd:sb

Tags: sensebox

I tried to connect to my sensebox using the Serial Monitor in the Arduino IDE.

The IDE couldn't connect. The error message is:

> Unknown FQBN: missing platform release arduino:samd referenced by board sensebox:samd:sb. Could not connect to COM7 serial port.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was:
I only had the "sensebox SAMD Boards" board installed.

After I also installed "Arduino SAMD Boards (32bits ARM Cortex-M0+)" it worked.

The [installation instructions](https://docs.sensebox.de/arduino/board-support-package-installieren/#anleitung-f%C3%BCr-windows) do mention this second package, but I still missed it.